# Scraping Javascript object with R package V8

Tags: r, v8

I have been able to read javascript to V8, but I don't understand how I can inspect what variables I actually have in that data. My original data is very long and I'm not sure what is in it. So how one finds out what is in their data?

```
library(V8)
```

`library(purrr)`

```
example_text <- "var data = {\"id\":{\"23\":\"Jason\",\"24\":\"Kris\"},\"Lim\":{\"1\":15,\"2\":30,\"3\":45,\"4\":60},\"time\":\"2013-02-08 12:00:00\"};\r\n       var total = 103;\r\n        var map = {\"54\":\"776\",\"32\":\"43\"};"

ctx <- v8()

example_text %>% 
  stringi::stri_split_lines() %>% 
  purrr::flatten_chr() %>% 
  ctx$eval()

ctx$get("data")
```

How do I find out about other vars' `total` and `map`? Or is there away to get all out in one go?

Comment: Where does `flatten_chr` and the `%>%` operator come from? Please list all packages used.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot tidyverse

Comment: Please avoid using `library(tidyverse)` and only specify the specific packages that you are using functions from.

Comment: Understood, I named packages to code.